# Spectrum of the derivative operator: What's wrong in my argument?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Consider the Banach space $X=C[0,1]$ of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the supremum norm. If we consider the following unbounded operator $A$ defined on its domain $D(A)=\{f\in C^1[0,1]:f(0)=1\}$ by $Af=f'$. I am interested in finding its spectrum. So if $g\in X$, then $g$ has a unique antecedent $f$ by the application $\lambda-A$ which is given by the formula $$f(x)=e^{\lambda x}-\int_0^xe^{\lambda(x-y)}g(y)dy.$$
That is $\lambda-A$ is invertible for every $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$. Which means that the spectrum of $A$ is empty.

Now in the other hand, for each $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$, if we consider the function $f_\lambda$ defined by $f_\lambda(x)=e^{\lambda x}$, then $f_\lambda\neq0$, $f_\lambda\in D(A)$ and $Af_\lambda=\lambda f_\lambda$, which means that the *point spectrum* is the whole complex plane. But this contradicts the fact that the whole spectrum is empty !!?

Comment: In the infinite dimensional case, the fact that $\lambda-A$ is onto doesn't mean it is bijective. That's why your argument fails.

Comment: on a Banach space (on $\mathbb{R}$), the spectrum is the set $\sigma(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $c \not \in \sigma(A) \Longleftrightarrow (A - c I)^{-1}$ exists and is bounded ? in that case, $\sigma(A) = \mathbb{R}$ since $(A-c I)[e^{cx}] = 0$ for every $c\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: and @user165633 you said you are considering the $\mathbb{R}$ vector space $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, hence the spectrum is $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{C}$. and I don't understand your so said inverse operator (where $e^{\lambda x}, e^{\lambda (x-y)}$ come from ?)

Comment: $D(A)$ is not a vector space. Do you possibly mean $f(0) = 0$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I think this is the problem !!!

Comment: @user165633 I think you think right. ;-)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp this might be a good fake proof :)