# Spectrum of Derivative Operator

Tags: derivatives, spectral-theory

Good evening!  Given the operator $A$ acting on $L^2(0,1)$ with $Au = u'$, $\mathcal{D}(A) = \{u \in H^1(0,1):u(1)=0\}$, I am trying to show that $A$'s spectrum is empty, which is stated as easy to show in the text. However, I am not entirely sure how to prove this, and I'm not entirely sure it is true due to this other (slightly confusing) Stack question: [Spectrum of the derivative operator: What's wrong in my argument?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1703867/spectrum-of-the-derivative-operator-whats-wrong-in-my-argument). Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks!